# Comment Templates Context Menu, an auto-comments user script

Tags: script, comments

If you are tired of typing the same comments into Stack Exchange sites over and over, you can use this add-on to insert any of your frequently written comments with a couple clicks.

### Installation

1. Install a user script extension (such as [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)) for your browser.  [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en) maintains a list of user script extensions that are available for various browsers.
2. [Click here to install `context-menu.user.js`](https://github.com/stephenostermiller/stack-exchange-comment-templates/raw/master/context-menu.user.js) within your user script manager.

### Getting started

Trigger a context menu on the field where you write a comment by right-clicking, long-pressing, or command-clicking (depending on your operating system.) A menu will pop up with a list of comments that can be inserted. Click one of them to insert it, or use the "Edit" button to change the comment templates.

### Features

- Right click on an empty comment field, or on the "Add a comment" link to bring up a context menu of comments that can be inserted.
- Also works for edit notes, flags, and flag handling responses.
- Does not show a context menu for comment boxes that have been filled in allowing you to use the standard context menu for features like spell check.
- An import/export text file format
- Load comments from a URL (Hosting comment templates on Github works great.)
- Comment templates are stored in user script storage that persists across all Stack Exchange sites (no need to configure your comments per site.)
- Set comment templates to be available only in specific contexts:

  - Only on specific types of comments (eg. comments on answers)
  - Only for moderators or for non-moderators
  - Only on specific sites (eg. stackoverflow.com)
  - Only for specific tags (eg. Java)
- Filter comments by keyword
- Warnings about comment templates that are too long

### Variables

The following variables are expanded by this code within comments:

- `$SITENAME`: The name of the current Stack Exchange site, eg "Stack Overflow"
- `$SITEURL`: The domain name of the current Stack Exchange site, eg `stackoverflow.com`. You usually don't need this variable, you can use links like `[editing help](/editing-help)` to link to URLs found on every StackExchange site.
- `$MYUSERID`: Your user id
- `$MYNAME`: Your user name (without spaces for @references)
- `$QUESTIONID`: The ID of the question at the top of the page
- `$OPID`: The user ID of the person who asked the question
- `$OPNAME`: The user name of the person who asked the question (without spaces for @references)
- `$OPREP`: The reputation of the person who asked the question
- `$POSTID`: The ID of the question or answer for which a comment is being written
- `$AUTHORID`: The user ID of the author of the question or answer for which a comment is being written
- `$AUTHORNAME`: The user name of the author of the question or answer for which a comment is being written (without spaces for @references)
- `$AUTHORREP`: The reputation of the author of the question or answer for which a comment is being written

In addition, Stack Exchange expands links such as `[meta]`, `[edit]`, and `[help]`. See [the documentation](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for the full list and explanations.

### SE-AutoReviewComments compatibility

I authored this project because [AutoReviewComments](/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) isn't currently maintained and is no longer fully functional. I wanted migration from it to be as painless as possible.

- The import/export format is very similar. Comment templates exported from SE-AutoReviewComments can be directly imported
- All SE-AutoReviewComments variables are supported

There are several features of SE-AutoReviewComments that are not implemented here:

- Displaying extended information about the author
- "See-through" mode
- JSONP export
- Showing the full comment text by default
- Adding a welcome message to comments for new users
- Direct extensions for Firefox or Chrome

## Github

If you want to suggest changes or report bugs please do so in the [Github repository for this project](https://github.com/stephenostermiller/stack-exchange-comment-templates).